# Android rxjava handle passing nullable to Single.just()

Tags: android, rx-java

I am trying to write a generic response handler for Retrofit, using `RxJava`. The API sends back a standard response object which has an `event` object that is always present, and a `data` object that can be null sometimes.

I have code written that works fine when its not null, but I get a NullPointerException when the `data` object is null.
It is a singleton object that I wrap all API call with, eg `ApiWrapper.makeCall(api.getUsers())` and this extracts the common `event` object and processes it, and then I just want to pass back the data object. If its null, I suppose I don't need to pass it back and can finish processing.

I have an extension function on Single that handles the response:

```
object ApiCallWrapper {

    var eventHandler: ((event: EventObject) -> Unit)? = null

    fun <T> makeCall(apiCall: Single<EventResponse<T>>): Single<T?> {
        return apiCall.handleResponse(eventHandler)
    }
}

fun <T> Single<EventResponse<T>>.handleResponse(eventHandler: ((event: EventObject) -> Unit)?): Single<T?> {
    return this
        .flatMap {
            eventHandler?.invoke(it.event)

            Single.just(it.data) // This line -> it.data can be null
        }
        .doOnError {
            Log.e("TAG", "handleResponse::doOnError", it)
        }
}
```

I am returning the type as `Single<T?>` but, as I'm not very experienced in RxJava, I'm trying to figure out a way to correctly return from this extension function. This means either returning the data object, or if its null, handling it gracefully (send back a null object or else stop processing and move to the next API call).

I've tried returning the data from `.doOnComplete` and I also tried changing the return type to `Maybe<T?>` but I get some error messages saying the return type needs to be Single.

So is there another function I'm missing so I can either return null data or stop Rxjava processing the request?

Thanks

Comment: RxJava 2.x does not support `null`. I don't know if 3.x does. You might consider wrapping your data in something else, such as `Optional`.

Comment: @CommonsWare `Optional` doesn't work as I then have to go and change every API call response to handle it being an `Optional<T>` instead of directly handling it as `T`. I haven't figured this out but changed the API to always return `{}` rather than `null`. Not ideal but it'll stop the app crashing!

Comment: "`Optional` doesn't work as I then have to go and change every API call response to handle it being an `Optional<T>` instead of directly handling it as `T`" -- it works, as I have used it. You just do not want to spend the effort. That is fine, but do not claim that it "doesn't work".

Comment: Yes, I mean it doesn't work as a solution to my problem as it defeats the purpose of what I'm trying to do. I've wrapped the `Single.just()` in `it.data?.let{}` and it compiles so I'm going with this option, eg: `response.data?.let { Single.just(it) }`. There's no other return from this code block so I'm hoping this is a valid solution.